# Can execution time of SOAP request be improved?

Tags: php, soap

I have a SOAP request I'm doing in PHP. It can take anywhere from 1-2 seconds to as much as 5 or more. This is on the slow side because the data is to be loaded and displayed on a web page. It can slow down the overall load time on the web page. I'm looking for ways to improve the performance of the SOAP request if that is feasible. I don't think it is practical to cache the data because the data is updated every minute. I have considered polling a SOAP request every minute and caching it, but to do that 24/7 might be considered hammer the 3rd-parties server.

This is in PHP in Linux. Would it improve the execution in a noticeable way if the SOAP request were done in another language such as C? Or it polling a SOAP request during expected heavy website traffic (such as the morning) every minute a better solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strategies depend on the amount of different calls you'd make.

You cannot really improve the Soap execution time itself. You have to wait as long as the request takes.

Is that request done for every user individually or is it always the same? Then caching for one minute will improve the situation in 55 of 60 seconds in every minute, assuming that one call takes 5 seconds, and any site request is served by that cache entry.

This only can be improved if you really make one request to the Soap server per minute to fill the cache before any of your users require the data.

On the other side, you can reduce fetching always uptodate data by making the cache entry last longer than one minute.

A very sophisticated system would try to know in advance if the user MIGHT actually need the Soap data, and trigger that request and cache filling without impacting the user, for example by adding the request to a queue that is executed independently. It can then fill the cache, and at the time the Soap request is needed, the cache is filled.

Comment: Yes, the request would be done for every user. I'm thinking of having a CRON job run every minute, and store the data in a MySQL TABLE. I'm thinking this would prevent the user from having to wait the 5 seconds or so for the SOAP request to be completed. The data doesn't change more often than once a minute.